# TwitterOauth: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, oop, twitter-oauth

I have the following code (taken from actual script):

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $auth_token=$row['oauth_token'];
 $auth_token_secret=$row['oauth_token_secret'];
 $apiconn = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $auth_token, $auth_token_secret);

 $API_result = $apiconn->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name' => $uname));
 echo $API_result . "<br />";

}
```

I keep getting error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in scriptpath on line 26
```

line 26 is

```
$apiconn = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $auth_token, $auth_token_secret);
```

I don't know why this is happening, because, example from [that library](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) does the same without generating error :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `var_dump($API_result)` instead of echoing it and see how you get what you actually want. I think this is just another example of PHP counting lines wrongly as regards giving line 26 (presumably something to do with different OS line endings, though I don't know for sure).